# Need to understand regexp_replace logic of given code

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I going through a oracle code and found this code:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT RTRIM (REGEXP_REPLACE ('ABC,CDE,ABC','([^,]*)(,\1)+($|,)','\1\3'),',') FROM DUAL;
```

**Output 1**:

```
ABC,CDE,ABC
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT RTRIM (REGEXP_REPLACE ('ABC,ABC,CDE','([^,]*)(,\1)+($|,)','\1\3'),',') FROM DUAL;
```

**Output 2**:

```
ABC,CDE
```

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT RTRIM (REGEXP_REPLACE ('ABC,ABC,CDE,CDE,ABC,CDE','([^,]*)(,\1)+($|,)','\1\3'),',') FROM DUAL;
```

**Output 3**:

```
ABC,CDE,ABC,CDE
```

though I know what this regexp_replace is doing but I need to understand what this regexp_replace is doing step by step and what it mean by each key word.I am able to find usage of individual syntax part but can't decipher it with combination.

Also if there is any website/book available to learn such complex usage of regexp_replace function, it would be great help.

Comment: What did google tell you when you searched for regex resources?

Comment: [Regex 101](https://www.regex101.com/) is a great website to understand a specific regexp. :)

Comment: Although Oracle regex is a bit specific, your regex can be checked at https://regex101.com/r/r9V7tH/1 - it works just the same with PCRE engine.